# How to connect Laravel application with MySQL with no username and password in Windows

Tags: php, mysql, windows, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and connecting with MySQL in Windows where I am not using any username and password in MySQL. It's showing an error when I am running `php artisan migrate` command :

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to
>   database 'rebelute_test'

My .env file is here:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel 
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:tSIeNfMf7bh6mxHuAHrhoaf+pzPxxFq69ABqlXZwtUw=
APP_DEBUG=true   
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=127.0.0.1
APP_LOG=daily
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=rebelute_test 
DB_USERNAME='' 
DB_PASSWORD=''
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log 
CACHE_DRIVER=file 
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120 
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 
REDIS_PASSWORD=null 
REDIS_PORT=6379
MAIL_DRIVER=log 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io 
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null 
MAIL_PASSWORD=null 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
PUSHER_APP_ID= 
PUSHER_APP_KEY= 
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default username of database is `root` check it on `DB_USERNAME` variable